# suitecrm rest api with php

Tags: php, rest, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am trying my first steps in SuiteCRM and managed to install, add some data and test it a bit.

As my goal is to use REST API through php would like to connect to the application.

I have found some examples however it does not seem to give me anything. Could I ask an expert to provide me a good starting point (or a code) as an example to read users or accounts out of the App through API?

I have tried the following link:

http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/Web_Services/Examples/REST/PHP/Retrieving_a_List_of_Fields_From_a_Module/

giving the right URL and login credentials however I haven't even got a single line back.

So farI have done:

- Installed the SuiteCRM with the API
- checked the URL and it can give me back the default info.
- I have added a print_r("hello"); line that printed every time I run the script.
- Checked this link: https://suitecrm.com/forum/developer-help/7424-rest-api-documentation with the default logins with no luck.

If anyone has any method to test it further, please add in comment as I would like to learn.

EDIT:

Here is the code:

print_r("hello"); - this is working

```
$url = "http://http://demo.suiteondemand.com/service/v4_1/rest.php";
$username = "will";
$password = "will";

function call($method, $parameters, $url)
{
    ob_start();
    $curl_request = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

    $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($parameters);

    $post = array(
         "method" => $method,
         "input_type" => "JSON",
         "response_type" => "JSON",
         "rest_data" => $jsonEncodedData
    );

    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $result = curl_exec($curl_request);
    curl_close($curl_request);

    $result = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);
    $response = json_decode($result[1]);
    ob_end_flush();

    return $response;
}

//login ---------------------------------------- 
$login_parameters = array(
     "user_auth" => array(
          "user_name" => $username,
          "password" => md5($password),
          "version" => "1"
     ),
     "application_name" => "RestTest",
     "name_value_list" => array(),
);

$login_result = call("login", $login_parameters, $url);

/*
echo "<pre>";
print_r($login_result); //nothing
echo "</pre>";
*/

//get session id
$session_id = $login_result->id;

//retrieve fields -------------------------------- 
$get_module_fields_parameters = array(

     //session id
     'session' => $session_id,

     //The name of the module from which to retrieve records
     'module_name' => 'Accounts',

     //Optional. Returns vardefs for the specified fields. An empty array will return all fields.
     'fields' => array(
         'id',
         'name',
     ),
);

$get_module_fields_result = call("get_module_fields", $get_module_fields_parameters, $url);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($get_module_fields_result); //nothing again
echo "</pre>";
```

?>

the html source that I am getting is:

```
hello<pre></pre>
```

Points:

1. I am using the demo website link and logins that should work (I believe)
2. tested on my site install as well but had the same result
3. the script would not through any error messages
4. the URL works from the browser even on the demo site

Additional info:

I have managed to call the demo website with ... helps so I wanted to turn back to my website that has no https and only talks with http but again it is a brick wall. Please see the code that I changed:

```
    $url = "http://my_domain.com/suiteCRM/service/v4_1/rest.php";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";

function call($method, $parameters, $url)
{
    ob_start();
    $curl_request = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

Comment: Can't say anything without looking your code. But http://www.urdhva-tech.com/blogs/sugarcrm-rest-api-example example can help definitely. I have used it before.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the hint. I have received a "Error handling result." message on the demo website, it is also v2. Have you had recently any luck with it?

Answer (score 4):

Ahh, never thought it would be an issue but you made a typo error. Check you URL for rest end point. You need to point it HTTPS with proper structure. Following is updated (working fine for me) code:

```
$url = "https://demo.suiteondemand.com/service/v4_1/rest.php";
$username = "will";
$password = "will";

function call($method, $parameters, $url)
{
    ob_start();
    $curl_request = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

    $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($parameters);

    $post = array(
         "method" => $method,
         "input_type" => "JSON",
         "response_type" => "JSON",
         "rest_data" => $jsonEncodedData
    );

    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $result = curl_exec($curl_request);
    curl_close($curl_request);

    $result = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);
    $response = json_decode($result[1]);
    ob_end_flush();

    return $response;
}

//login ---------------------------------------- 
$login_parameters = array(
     "user_auth" => array(
          "user_name" => $username,
          "password" => md5($password),
          "version" => "1"
     ),
     "application_name" => "RestTest",
     "name_value_list" => array(),
);

$login_result = call("login", $login_parameters, $url);

/*
echo "<pre>";
print_r($login_result); //nothing
echo "</pre>";
*/

//get session id
$session_id = $login_result->id;

//retrieve fields -------------------------------- 
$get_module_fields_parameters = array(

     //session id
     'session' => $session_id,

     //The name of the module from which to retrieve records
     'module_name' => 'Accounts',

     //Optional. Returns vardefs for the specified fields. An empty array will return all fields.
     'fields' => array(
         'id',
         'name',
     ),
);

$get_module_fields_result = call("get_module_fields", $get_module_fields_parameters, $url);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($get_module_fields_result); //nothing again
echo "</pre>";
```

It produce following output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [module_name] => Accounts
    [table_name] => accounts
    [module_fields] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => id
                    [type] => id
                    [group] => 
                    [id_name] => 
                    [label] => ID
                    [required] => 1
                    [options] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [related_module] => 
                    [calculated] => 
                    [len] => 
                )

            [name] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => name
                    [type] => name
                    [group] => 
                    [id_name] => 
                    [label] => Name:
                    [required] => 1
                    [options] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [related_module] => 
                    [calculated] => 
                    [len] => 150
                )

        )

    [link_fields] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: hello again! and thank you for your clue. My website does not have a HTTPS hence it does not work. Is there are way around it? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: simply change URL from HTTPS to HTTP. Hopefully that will work for you.

Comment: hi many thanks for that I have tried with the http and with the IP address and it didn't produce the same info. This is might be SSL or my installation... I don't know yet.

Comment: Hi Star I edited my question with the http code. will it ignore the http url?

Comment: there is restriction from SuiteCRM for HTTP or HTTPS. if still things doesn't work for you then it might be related to server not HTTP or HTTPs of suitecrm instance.